# Search with ajax , "like" in array

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, search

Please help with search script

```
$("#search").on("keyup",function(){
    var search=$("#search").val();
    search=search.replace(/  +/g, ' ');
    if(search.length>=1){
        var result=search.split("");
        $.ajax({  
            type: 'POST',  
            url: "{{URL('/searchajax')}}", 
            data: 
                { 
                    search:result
                },
            success: function(data) {
                $("#searchresult").css("display","block");
                if(data.length>0){
                    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                        $.each(data[i], function( index, value ) {
                            $("#itemssearch").append("<a href='{{URL('/product')}}/"+value.id+"'>\
                                                            <li>"+value.originalname+value.name+"</li>\n\
                                                        </a>\n\
                                                        ");

                            });
                    }
                }else{
                      ...
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

```
public function searchajax(Request $request){
    $search=$request->search;
        $return=DB::table("products")
                ->where('originalname', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')
                ->orWhere('name', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')
                ->orderby("products.table_id")
                ->take(5)
                ->get();

    return response()->json($return);
}
```

1. if have search word "iphone 7s" how to search first "iphone" then "7s" and get all result in one variable
2. if have search word "iphone 7s" how to search first "iphone" then
   "7s" and get all result in one variable

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want to apply `orWhere()` pair for each word with `foreach`:

```
$words = explode(' ', $search);

$result = Product::query();

foreach ($words as $word) {
    $result = $result->orWhere('originalname', 'like', '%'.$word.'%')
                     ->orWhere('name', 'like', '%'.$word.'%');
}

$result = $result->orderby("products.table_id")->take(5)->get();
```

Comment: if you can help me with this code , how to select rows fromm mysql where like all word , if i have "Iphone 7s blue" and i search "iphone blue" then get just rows who have just this words

Comment: if you understood me , becouse i don't know eng language

Comment: sql sintax , Select * From products where name like %iphone% and name like %blue%

Comment: Use two `orWhere()` closures. One for name, another one is for originalname. Inside closure use foreach and `where()` to add all words to the search.

Comment: i have in mysql Samsung galaxy s7, samsung galaxy s6, samsung galaxy s8,
if i search samsung s7 , this code give me all samsungs
how to modify for select just rows who have just this words
sintax Select * from products where name like %samsung% and name like %s7%

Comment: Check my previous comment. It'll work for this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

example with CodeIgniter
controller

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    /**
     * Index Page for this controller.
     *
     * Maps to the following URL
     *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome
     *  - or -
     *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome/index
     *  - or -
     * Since this controller is set as the default controller in
     * config/routes.php, it's displayed at http://example.com/
     *
     * So any other public methods not prefixed with an underscore will
     * map to /index.php/welcome/<method_name>
     * @see https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->model('common_model');
        $var1='engineering';

        $where=" id !='0'";
        $a['reco']=$this->common_model->get_entry_by_data('collages',false,$where);

        $this->load->view('welcome_message',$a);


    }


    public function ajaxcall()
    {   
    $searchval=$this->input->post('lalla');
    $this->load->model('common_model');

        $where="`city` like '%".$searchval."%' or `deparment` like '%".$searchval."%'";
        $a=$this->common_model->get_entry_by_data('collages',false,$where);


        $result='';
        $result="<table>
        <tr><td>name</td><td>city</td><td>deparment</td></tr>";
        if(!empty($a))
        { 
         foreach($a as $recos){
        $result.="<tr><td>". $recos['name']."</td><td>". $recos['city']."</td><td>". $recos['deparment']."</td></tr>"; 
        }
        }else{
            $result.="<tr><td>no result</td><td>no result</td><td>no result</td></tr>";

        }
        $result.="</table>";

        echo $result;



}
}
```

view example

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Welcome to CodeIgniter</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">

    ::selection { background-color: #E13300; color: white; }
    ::-moz-selection { background-color: #E13300; color: white; }

    body {
        background-color: #fff;
        margin: 40px;
        font: 13px/20px normal Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        color: #4F5155;
    }

    a {
        color: #003399;
        background-color: transparent;
        font-weight: normal;
    }

    h1 {
        color: #444;
        background-color: transparent;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #D0D0D0;
        font-size: 19px;
        font-weight: normal;
        margin: 0 0 14px 0;
        padding: 14px 15px 10px 15px;
    }

    code {
        font-family: Consolas, Monaco, Courier New, Courier, monospace;
        font-size: 12px;
        background-color: #f9f9f9;
        border: 1px solid #D0D0D0;
        color: #002166;
        display: block;
        margin: 14px 0 14px 0;
        padding: 12px 10px 12px 10px;
    }

    #body {
        margin: 0 15px 0 15px;
    }

    p.footer {
        text-align: right;
        font-size: 11px;
        border-top: 1px solid #D0D0D0;
        line-height: 32px;
        padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
        margin: 20px 0 0 0;
    }

    #container {
        margin: 10px;
        border: 1px solid #D0D0D0;
        box-shadow: 0 0 8px #D0D0D0;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
    <h1>Welcome to CodeIgniter!</h1>

    <div id="body">

        <input type="text" name="searchbox" value="" id="searchbox"/>
        <button name="btn" id="btn">search</button>
        <div id="replace">
        <table>
        <tr><td>name</td><td>city</td><td>deparment</td></tr>
        <?php foreach($reco as $recos){?>
        <tr><td><?php echo $recos['name'];?></td><td><?php echo $recos['city'];?></td><td><?php echo $recos['deparment'];?></td></tr>
        <?php }?>
        </table>
        </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
<script>
$("#btn").click(function() {
    var searchval=$("#searchbox").val();

 $.ajax({
        url: "index.php/Welcome/ajaxcall", 
        type: "post",
        data: {'lalla':searchval} ,
        success: function (response) {
                   $("#replace").html(response);

        },



    });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this Autocomplete, this code I used in laravel 5.4

```
$('#search').on('input', function(){
    var search = $('#search').val(); //search input var

    if(search.length == 0){
        //do something if value of search box is empty
    } else {
        $('#search').autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response){
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'search', //route
                    data: { search:search },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type: 'post',
                    success: function(data){
                        //here is your data
                    },
                    error: function(){
                        alert('Could not load the data');
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: my jquery work , i don't know how php select data with N Words

Comment: `autocomplete` is not included in the jQuery core